# Regex specific format with numbers separated with commas (in Python)

Tags: python, regex, format

I am trying to check for specific format to be true and the function to return either 1 or 0 if the format is correct or incorrect. Format that I am trying to use would be numbers separated with commas and spaces (i.e. 
`0, 13, 24, 27`). My current code works to some extent, but it does not detect that only one space is in front of a number and if I were to add some random text in the middle (i.e. `0, 13, 24asd, 27`), it still detects this as a valid format. How should I go about fixing this?

Code:

```
def format_placement(string):
    is_correct = 0
    pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+)(?:,(\d+)*)')
    if re.findall(pattern, string):
        is_correct = 1
    return is_correct
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) to match the full string with the pattern, and add a space to the regex after a comma (or `\s` if you allow any whitespace):

```
def format_placement(string):
    is_correct = 0
    if re.fullmatch(r'\d+(?:, \d+)*', string):
        is_correct = 1
    return is_correct
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OfvJBn/1) (`^` indicated the start of a string and `$` marks the end of string, these anchors are not necessary when you use `re.fullmatch`).